# How to have a service create a user with read/write privileges?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a service that I recently wrote, but don't want it to use the Local System account. It is running under a local user account (non-admin), and needs to be able to read/write to a directory. I have tried running it under both Local Service and a virtual account, neither which worked. Is there a way to have the service create it's own user, set the specific privileges it needs and then change to run under that account? Is this possible? The service will be installed remotely via BigFix (which does have admin rights), so installing the service is not an issue. It could even be installed initially with Local System, but I would want to change it to a different account on it's first run.

Thanks

Comment: That would be a dream come true for every hacker in the world

Comment: No. How would you expect this to work anyway? The service can't start without an account, so how would it start in the first place to create it's own account? This would also be a massive security hole that malware and hackers could sail supertankers through.

Comment: Got it. Didn't totally think it was possible, but wanted to ask anyway. I will have to create a local user with the correct privileges and then have it use that user.